# how to encrypt data from a database query array in laravel controller?

Tags: arrays, database, laravel

```
$shares_data = Share::where('member_id', $member_id)->get();
```

I want to all data of **$shares_data** array in different variable. I am using Laravel 5.2

Comment: you can use `foreach` for get data from this query

Comment: "I want to all data.." It seems you forgot the verb. No idea what you want to do.

Comment: here is a array of a database table, i want all data in different variable as for example: name, mobile_no, email are the column names of that table. I want `name` value in a $name variable, `mobile_no` in a $mobile and `email` value in a $email variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly i used the code in the controller:

```
foreach($shares_data as $key=>$share_data):
$name= $share_data->name;
$mobile= $share_data->mobile;
endforeach
```

but it was not working. then try the code below:

```
foreach($shares_data as $key=>$share_data){
$name= $share_data->name;
$mobile= $share_data->mobile;
}
```

Now it's working. Thank you very much Saman for your kind help.